# 1C Битрикс: Как связать почтовый шаблон с экземпляром инфоблока 'Форма'?

Tags: битрикс, 1с

Я нигде не вижу ни галочки в интерфейсе Формы или Шаблона, ни параметра в вызове формы для этого.

Я просто хочу связать Форму с тем шаблоном для отправки писем, который мне нужен.